# CSV file double-spacing lines

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

I am having trouble with OpenOffice Calc opening a CSV file that I create using StreamWriter C#. When it opens it has empty lines between every line that should be there(double-spaced). There seems to be some kind of doubling of the carriage returns. When I open it in Notepad it reads correctly. When I changed the program to write integers instead of strings the problem went away. It seems to be adding a return on the end of each string and then the formating adds another return that I'm not seeing.

Output looks like this...

```
1...

2...

3...
```

Output should look like this...

```
1...
2...
3...
```

Here is the ForEach loop I use to write the List to file...

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\andy\Arduino StreamWriter.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            foreach (string element in SerialPortString)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }
```

There is only one field of data per line, so there are no delimiters, just new lines. I tried formatting so that it would write with quotes around each field hoping that would eliminate confusion for the CSV format, but I wasn't able to figure that out either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So in notepad it looks ok?  I would guess there is a \n on the end of the `element` string? if so you end up with \n\r\n - notepad will ignore the first \n other applications that pay attention to linux endings  will not.

Comment: I just went back to make this change and that did eliminate the problem. But I am not sure why this is. Using the Write method should append all elements of the list to the first line, but for some reason the loop is automatically inserting a Return after each write.

Comment: There must be a \n on the end of all the `element` values, i.e. if you look at `var x = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(element.ToString());` in the debugger it's probably 10.

Comment: put a `watch` on the element variable and see what additional characters are showing up at the end of the stream. Also check how the `SerialPortStream` is populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
sw.WriteLine(element);
```

to

```
sw.WriteLine(element.Trim());
```

or maybe

```
sw.WriteLine(element.TrimEnd());
```

Trim the element first. That will remove any LineFeeds or other whitespace characters around the 'edges' of the characters. Then the StreamWriter's CRLFs will be the only newlines present.

Comment: `TrimEnd()` is more effecient.

Comment: dont think there is a TrimEnd() method that does not expect an array of chars to be removed...

Comment: Thank you, this did work. I'm not exactly sure what it is trimming exactly, but adding Trim() to the element fixed the issue.

Comment: There will be a linefeed on the end of each line. Somewhere in the plumbing your data is being split by carriage return, which leaves the linefeed behind as debris.

Comment: I was debugging another setup and I discovered that the Serial.ReadLine() was adding "\r" to all the strings. So, they all had values of "xxx\r" which was causing the second mystery return. The strings are all numbers and the one I saw was "167\r".

Comment: I reckon the lines were separated by CRLF, and that within ReadLine() it's calling Split() by either CR or CRLF. When I split by CRLF, it only actually uses the CR and leaves the LF behind.    Well, now you know, you'll spot it in other people's work :)